# Adding a viewController as subView programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am building an Iphone app.

I need to display a settings Menu to the user when a button is clicked. The menu will NOT be covering the whole screen and there is a specific location I want it to appear. How should I do that?

I understand how to set the hidden property of a subview to give the illusion that the subview is not onScreen. However, I need a view controller for this subview ( meaning .m and .h files as well). So How can I add this subview programmatically at a specific location.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is very much the behavior of a UIPopoverController. Unfortunately, that is only available for use on iPad's and not iPhone's or iPod Touches. So if you want to develop this you will need to develop this from scratch.

It's not a UI pattern you see much on the iPhone due to the screen size, but I imagine you will need to build up a custom UIView and add it the main window view with a specific size (smaller than screen size) and with the view's frame.origin set to a value other than (0,0).

Just make sure that what you are trying to achieve falls within Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myView addSubview:myViewController.view];
myViewController.view.frame=...
```