# Display ViewController as PopUpSubview?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, popup, subview, popupwindow

I have a ViewController with xib,.h,.m files. Now i want to display it as a popUpView in another viewController. so I did like this...

```
Second *view2 = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
[view2.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 400)];
{self.view addSubview:view2.view];
```

but the problem here I am able to set frame randomly, but the viewController contains a textField and button. They are not getting added at random positions on the view like some textField comes out of the frame of view added.

After some googling i find this, but this not enough to solve my issue.

[Adding a ViewConroller's View as subview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955968/adding-a-viewcontroller-as-subview-programmatically)

How to solve it...

Comment: Hi, what your ViewController do ? it's a login/pass pop-up ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are changing the frame of the view in your view controller but not handling the repositioning of the elements inside the view. What you can do is override the layoutSubviews method in the view so that when the frame changes the text fields reposition themselves.

You will have to create an actual UIView subclass which will layout the text fields,

```
@interface SecondView : UIView{

}

@implementation SecondView{
    - (void) layoutSubviews{
      //self.frame would be to most up-to-date frame that you just set
    }
}
```

Your UIViewController will just create the view like so,

```
@interface Second : UIViewController{    
}


@implementation Second{
    - (void) loadView{
        self.view = [[[SecondView alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
}
```